# What encryption does Electrum use for private keys in wallets?

Tags: wallet, encryption, electrum, passphrase

Electrum can encrypt the private keys in wallets with a user entered password. But what encryption algorithm is used? I'd hope it is reasonably strong crypto. I've looked at the Electrum docs and can't find specifics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electrum uses AES-256-CBC to encrypt wallets.  The key is sha256(sha256("your password")).

Electrum wallet source:
https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/lib/wallet.py

slowaes library:
https://code.google.com/p/slowaes/source/browse/trunk/python/aes.py