# Decrypting wallet

Tags: electrum, cryptography, encryption

I'm seeking assistance with understanding the technical aspects of how Electrum wallets handle parsing errors and potential solutions for resolving them. My friend has encountered a recurring issue where the Electrum wallet fails to parse its wallet file during the opening process. While this issue has occurred previously and the wallet eventually worked again, it is currently persistently unresponsive. We have access to the wallet's password but not the seed phrase.

Could you provide insights or advice on the underlying mechanisms causing parsing errors in Electrum wallets and any potential cryptographic approaches to address this issue?

Comment: Related [What does the electrum wallet file contains?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116922/13866) and [What encryption does Electrum use for private keys in wallets?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/16765/13866) I would decrypt then check the JSON.